# Analyzing coverage of numba-wrapped functions

Tags: pytest, numba, coverage.py

I've written [a python module](https://github.com/moble/spherical_functions), much of which is wrapped in `@numba.jit` decorators for speed.  I've also written lots of tests for this module, which I run ([on Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/moble/spherical_functions)) with `py.test`.  Now, I'm trying to look at the coverage of these tests, using `pytest-cov`, which is just a plugin that relies on `coverage` (with hopes of integrating all of this will [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/)).

Unfortunately, it seems that using `numba.jit` on all those functions makes `coverage` think that the functions are never used -- which is kind of the case.  So I'm getting basically no reported coverage with my tests.  This isn't a huge surprise, since `numba` is taking that code and compiling it, so the code itself really never is used.  But I was hoping there'd be some of that magic you see with python some times...

Is there any useful way to combine these two excellent tools?  Failing that, is there any other tool I could use to measure coverage with numba?

[I've made a minimal working example showing the difference [here](https://github.com/moble/python-coveralls-example).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing might be to disable the numba JIT during coverage measurement.  That relies on you trusting the correspondence between the Python code and the JIT'ed code, but you need to trust that to some extent anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried that would be the case.  Unfortunately, my tests take about 15 minutes even with numba, and I estimate they'd take about a day without it, so disabling numba is not going to work for me.  And I can't see any way to reduce the time they would take without reducing coverage.  Anyway, thanks for your answer and a very nice piece of code!  :)

Comment: Specifically, you disable jit by setting the `NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT` environment variable to a non-zero value.

Comment: This works, but it changes the behaviour of the function.  Some operations are valid on numpy arrays but invalid on numba arrays and vice-versa, and thus the unit test would fail to catch some failures with numba disabled.

Comment: How would you go about disabling numba JIT during coverage measurement @Ned?
I currently have a couple coverage options specified in my pyproject.toml file and am struggling to figure out how to disable JIT for coverage measurements only.

Comment: You would define the NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT environment variable when you run your coverage measurement.  Coverage.py doesn't have a feature to do that for you.

Answer (score 5):

Not that this answers the question, but I thought I should advertise another way that someone might be interested in working on.  There's probably something really beautiful that could be done using `llvm-cov`.  Presumably, this would have to be implemented within numba, and the llvm code would have to be instrumented, which would require some flag somewhere.  But since numba knows about the correspondence between lines of python code and llvm code, there must be something that could be implemented by somebody more clever than I am.